# IOS7 NSURLConnection nothing happens

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection

I am quite a newbie to IOS programming and want to user's location to server. I followed iOS developer library and tutorials on the Internet but nothing happens when I run the code. I am using the iOS simulator and it gives me mock locations well and I get `NSURLConnection` instance. However, nothing happens on server-side.

```
#import "JLSViewController.h"
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
#import "JLSEventData.h"

@interface JLSViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *locations;

@end

@implementation JLSViewController

NSMutableData *responseData = nil;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.locations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)enabledStateChanged:(id)sender
{
    if (self.switchEnabled.on)
    {
        [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    }
    else
    {
        [self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
    }
}

- (void)beginBackgroundUpdateTask: (CLLocation *)location {

}

- (void)endBackgroundUpdateTask {

}

#pragma mark - CLLocationManagerDelegate
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
    if (newLocation == nil) {
        return;
    }

    if (oldLocation != nil) {
        if (newLocation.coordinate.latitude == oldLocation.coordinate.latitude &&
            newLocation.coordinate.longitude == oldLocation.coordinate.longitude) {
            return;
        }
    }

    NSError *error = nil;
    JLSEventData *eventData = [[JLSEventData alloc] initWithLocation: newLocation];

    NSString *strData = [eventData toJSON:error];
    if (error != nil){
        return;
    }

    if (self.locations.count>5)
        [self.locations removeObjectAtIndex:0];

    [self.locations addObject:strData];
    NSData *requestBodyData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:self.locations options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
    if (error != nil){
        return;
    }

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        //[self beginBackgroundUpdateTask:newLocation];

        // Send a synchronous request
        NSMutableURLRequest * urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: "http://localhost:8080/mywebservice"]];
        [urlRequest setValue:@"application/json; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [urlRequest setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
        [urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        //[urlRequest setTimeoutInterval:20];

        //NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject
        urlRequest.HTTPBody = requestBodyData;

        // Create url connection and fire request
        [urlRequest setHTTPBody:[NSData dataWithBytes:[strData UTF8String] length:strlen([strData UTF8String])]];

        NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest delegate:self];
        if (conn!=nil){
            //receivedData = nil;
        }
    });
}

#pragma mark - NSURLConnection Delegate
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    NSLog(@"==>didReceiveResponse");
    // A response has been received, this is where we initialize the instance var you created
    // so that we can append data to it in the didReceiveData method
    // Furthermore, this method is called each time there is a redirect so reinitializing it
    // also serves to clear it
    responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    NSLog(@"==>didReceiveData");
    // Append the new data to the instance variable you declared
    [responseData appendData:data];
}

- (NSCachedURLResponse *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
                  willCacheResponse:(NSCachedURLResponse*)cachedResponse {
    // Return nil to indicate not necessary to store a cached response for this connection
    return nil;
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    // The request is complete and data has been received
    // You can parse the stuff in your instance variable now
    NSLog(@"Succeeded! Received %d bytes of data",[responseData length]);

    responseData = nil;
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    // The request has failed for some reason!
    // Check the error var
    NSLog(@"Connection failed! Error - %@ %@",
          [error localizedDescription],
          [[error userInfo] objectForKey:NSURLErrorFailingURLStringErrorKey]);
}
/*
 *
 */
- (void)parseData {
    //Do something
}

@end
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked whether your NSURLConnection call is ever reached? ( with breakpoints or NSLog ? )

Comment: Yes, NSURLConnection instance is not null, does it mean connection has been eatablished, does it?: conn======><NSURLConnection: 0x8e29290> Even though, I think it should give me error anyway if there is any error, isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing the NSURLConnection on a separate thread. And the thread is exiting before the response is received. You either need to do the NSURLConnection on the main thread or you need to keep the thread running until the response is received.

Comment: Thanks, I removed dispatch_async and it works now. It looks it does not need dispatch_async because it is already asynchronous. How about if is synchronous?

Comment: A POST will always be asynchronous. You can do a HTTP GET synchronously by using NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:<url>